# Jsoup unescapes special characters

Tags: html, character-encoding, escaping, jsoup

I'm using Jsoup to remove all the images from an HTML page.
I'm receiving the page through an HTTP response - which also contains the content charset.

The problem is that Jsoup unescapes some special characters.

For example, for the input:

```html
<html><head></head><body><p>isn&rsquo;t</p></body></html>
```

After running

```
String check = "<html><head></head><body><p>isn&rsquo;t</p></body></html>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(check);
System.out.println(doc.outerHtml());
```

I get:

```html
<html><head></head><body><p>isn’t</p></body></html><p></p>
```

I want to avoid changing the html **in any other way except for removing the images.**

By using the command:

```
doc.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false).charset("ASCII").escapeMode(EscapeMode.extended);
```

I do get the correct output but I'm sure there are cases where that charset won't be good. I just want to use the charset specified in the HTTP header and I'm afraid this will change my document in ways I can't predict.
Is there any other cleaner method for removing the images without changing anything else inadvertently?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a workaround not involving any charset except the one specified in the HTTP header.

```
String check = "<html><head></head><body><p>isn&rsquo;t</p></body></html>".replaceAll("&([^;]+?);", "**$1;");

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(check);

doc.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false).escapeMode(EscapeMode.extended);

System.out.println(doc.outerHtml().replaceAll("\\*\\*([^;]+?);", "&$1;"));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<html><head></head><body><p>isn&rsquo;t</p></body></html>
```

**DISCUSSION**

> *I wish there was a solution in Jsoup's API* - @dlv

Using Jsoup'API would require you to write a custom NodeVisitor. It would leads to (re)inventing some existing code inside Jsoup. The custom Nodevisitor would generate back an HTML escape code instead of a unicode character.

Another option would involve writing a custom character encoder. The default UTF-8 character encoder can encode `&rsquo;`. This is why Jsoup doesn't preserve the original escape sequence in the final HTML code.

Any of the two above options represents a big coding effort. Ultimately, an enhancement could be added to Jsoup for letting us choose how to generate the characters in the final HTML code : hexadecimal escape (`&#AB;`), decimal escape (`&#151;`), the original escape sequence (`&rsquo;`) or write the encoded character (which is the case in your post).

Comment: Thank you, I will use this for now although I wish there was a solution in Jsoup's API.

Comment: @Ravisha You can find this information in the "What's new" section on this page : https://jsoup.org/download

Comment: I ran into an issue where a client had multiple asterisks in their content and this logic was prefixing unwanted ampersands to the content.  Instead of the asterisk character (*), I used an invisible ASCII 31 (unit separator).

Comment: My text contains numerical entities, like &#224;, and this method replaces them by html entities, like &agrave;. Is there a mean to avoid that?